# Shortcuts for view modes in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't find what is the shortcut for toggling of **full screen** and **distraction free** viewing modes in IntelliJ IDEA. My questions are:

- Do those shortcuts even exist?
- Can they be defined as some custom shortcuts?
- Is there a way to create macros? (by pressing one button toggle both modes)
- Is there a plugin of some sort that does this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortcut does not exist by the default configuration (as seen [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intellij-idea-viewing-modes.html#d824162e201), and in [this YouTube video that showcases its use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVwE8MFgYig)).

[image]

You can assign it (distraction free example) yourself by going to `File > Settings > Keymap` and type `distract` in the filter field (or expand the `Main menu > View > Toggle Distraction Free mode` tree). Right click the item and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut` (or read [this manual on how to assign shortcuts in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html)).

Answer (score 17):

i would like to add to the existing answer, that there is indeed an indirect keyboard shortcut to change view mode.

```
ctrl+` > 4 > 1 (for presentation mode)
ctrl+` > 4 > 2 (for distraction free mode)
```

*tested on intellij idea v18.1.4 ultimate edition*

Comment: Thanks so much! It's not very practical to click through the menus every time, so this helps a lot..

Comment: I can kiss you for this

Answer (score 4):

In IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.2, the keyboard shortcuts are

```
ctrl + ` > 5 > 1 (for presentation mode)
ctrl + ` > 5 > 2 (for distraction free mode)
```